# How to get total count or total items of an index in elasticsearch using nodejs

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, graphql, elasticsearch-2.0

I am trying to get the total count of an index of elasticsearch using nodejs, but i don't know how to get the count. Can anyone please help me in this

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Use elasticsearch npm, and here is the reference of `count` api [Elasticsearch Count](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-count.html)

Answer (score 2):

According to their **nodejs** client [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/16.x/api-reference-6-8.html#api-count-6-8); you can use `count` api.

**First:** after install [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/elasticsearch); you should declare `client` object to use it to make requests:

```
const elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');
var client = new elasticsearch.Client({
    // depends on your configs
    host: 'http://localhost:9200',
    // your elasticsearch version
    apiVersion: '6.8'
});
```

**Second:** implement count functionality:

```
client.count({
    // required index
    index: 'indexname',
    body: {
        // you can count based on specific query or remove body at all
        query: { match_all: {} }
    }
})
.then(res => {
    // do whatever you want 
    console.log(res.count);
})
.catch(err => { 
    // handle error
});
```

That's it.